# TabControl: first TabItem static, rest from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` which contains a `TabControl`.
The TabControl will have 1 to n `TabItems`, that is: the first TabItem will always be there and its content will be the same for every instance of my UserControl, but the rest of the TabItems is supposed to come from my code-behind because I have to construct them dependent on some properties first.

My first try consisted of

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNS.MyControl"
             xmlns:local="MyNS"
             and the whole rest of the declarations>
  <Grid>
    <TabControl>
      <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Path="Tabs" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyControl}" />
      </TabControl.ItemsSource>
    <TabControl/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

where `Tabs` is declarated as `public IList Tabs { get { return ... } }` in the code-behind. It's not a dependency or attached property. It's just a simple field.
This works fine. Whatever I construct in the code-behind will be shown.

However, when I want to define the first TabItem manually I run into problems:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNS.MyControl"
             xmlns:local="MyNS"
             and the whole rest of the declarations>
  <Grid>
    <TabControl>
      <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
          <CollectionContainer>
            <CollectionContainer.Collection>
              <x:Array Type="TabItem">
                <TabItem Header="Test"/>
              </x:Array>
            </CollectionContainer.Collection>
          </CollectionContainer>
          <CollectionContainer>                        
            <CollectionContainer.Collection>
              <Binding Path="Tabs"
                       RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyControl}}"/>
            </CollectionContainer.Collection>                        
          </CollectionContainer>              
        </CompositeCollection>
      </TabControl.ItemsSource>
    <TabControl/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The first (static) item is always displayed, but it seems like the binding can't resolve my getter for `Tabs` anymore.

How can I define the first tab item manually (in the XAML) and fetch the rest from code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`{x:Reference}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNS.MyControl"
         xmlns:local="MyNS"
         x:Name="MyControl">

<!-- ... --->

<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Tabs, Source={x:Reference MyControl}}"/>
```

Comment: I had to move the complete `CompositeCollection` to the resources of the user control, but basically this works as intended.